# Element at the top of a Webview

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I should put an element (AdMob) at the top of a WebView, so when the WebView scrolls, the adv (AdMob) doesn't stay at the top of the page but scrolls with the page.
Is it possible?
If not, how can I do this?

Thanks!

*PS: I'm Italian, sorry for any error :|*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if you seprate the AdMob View and WebView and put them in a parent container such as a LinearLayout, and then place that layout in a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
          android:orientation="vertical"   
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                 ads:adSize="BANNER"
                 ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                 ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
          <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
      </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I want the opposite. The AdMob inside of the WebView.
So if I scroll down the web page (WebView), the AdMob scrolls with the page and became invisible (because It's on the top and I just scrolled down).

Comment: @user3223863, I misunderstood what you wanted. Then how about you place both in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted this!
Thanks a lot! :)

PS: LinearLayout's `layout_height` should be `wrap_content`